# How to use globally imported packages in script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to put my interactive commands in a script, but I can't run the same commands in the script.

We are using a heavily packaged version of Python for our tests, we usually run tests in interactive mode, but now I want to place all the commands in a package. Below is an example using the time package.

In interactive mode:

```
>>> import time
>>> import myscript
```

In my script:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

I expected the script to refer to the globally imported packages and allow me to run sleep, but it says `NameError: global name 'time' is not defined`

How do I get my script to recognize all packages imported into the interactive terminal? We use thousands of packages in our toolkit, and I can't import them all into my script.

Comment: This is what's supposed to happen. Scripts need to define the imports they need.

Comment: If you've got one script that *directly* uses thousands of packages, you're doing something seriously wrong (and you almost certainly would have realized that fact several thousand packages ago, so you're probably not directly using thousands of packages in one script).

Answer (score 1):

You have to import these libraries also in the .py file where you are going to use them. Python does not allow using them when they are imported in a higher level module, and that's the way it should be. Python, in some way, forces you being better programmer. Your script should be something like this:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have Module A:

```
import time
```

and Module B:

```
import A
```

then in module B I do have access to libraries that A imported, but they must be qualified thus:

```
A.time.sleep5()
```

In short, when you import a module, the public names in that module become accessible to the importer. But what you are attempting to do is quite different. In essence, you have Module A as:

```
import time
import B
```

And module B as:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

Module B neither directly imports the `time` package nor module A and therefore has no access to `time`. Being imported by a module that does have access to `time` does not confer to the imported module that access.

Comment: While `A.time.sleep` is technically a thing you can do, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: @user2357112 Nor was I suggesting it. I was just illustrating how public names come along for the ride.